# Running an endlessly looping animation on iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a simple UIView that draws itself using `drawRect:`. In order for the view to animate, the `drawRect` method needs to be called every say 0.05 seconds, so I use a repeating timer:

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self 
        selector:@selector(setNeedsDisplay) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I don't know too much about run loops, and threads, and all that system stuff, so I want to know if this is the correct way to run an animation? This timer repeats itself endlessly. Is this something I should be worried about? Will this block the main thread? What can I do to minimize overall impact on performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is not bad, but there are other ways to do it.

The timer's target method must take the timer as an argument, so instead of setting it for setNeedsDisplay directly, you should set up a method like this:

```
- (void)animationTimerDidFire:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    [myView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

If your view will always be visible, then you can just set-and-forget the timer. On the other hand, if it may go away because you switch to a different view, you will need to invalidate and recreate the timer as needed.

The main thread of your app uses a run loop and calls out to various methods in response to events, like user taps, system notifications (e.g., memory warning), and I/O arriving. If anything the run loop calls takes a long time to return, it will hold up everything in the queue. When you set up a timer, it is added to a list and that the run loop checks it each time through; if one of the timers is ready, it calls your method.

The end result is that timers are not exact: they might not fire as often as you like, might be called late, etc. Again, if your app is pretty simple, the main run loop won't be very busy and so a timer will probably be good enough. Just make sure your animation is based on actual time elapsed between calls, rather than assuming each call happens exactly 0.05 seconds apart.

#### Alternatives

If your animation simply involves flipping through some static images, UIImageView has some support for this.

If creating each frame of animation takes a noticeable amount of time (and you don't want to block the main thread), you could use a background queue to draw into an image (see `CGBitmapContextCreate` and `CGBitmapContextCreateImage`), then signal the main thread when a new image is ready to display. Anything that touches a view MUST happen on the main thread, but you can do the drawing on the background.

You also might want to read up on `CALayer` in the QuartzCore framework. This is what the UIView objects actually manipulate to draw on the screen. You may find that, instead of drawing, you can get the effects you want by manipulating some CALayer objects and letting Core Animation do the heavy lifting (e.g., you change the color from red to blue, Core Animation takes care of fading from one to the other).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are using an overridden or custom method, you should use recursion and a completion block for calling the animation. I find it works much better than a timer, since timers aren't always exact and can cause some animation issues if you have the animations timed for cycling.

EDIT: I don't know much about using drawRect: and calling [self setNeedsDisplay] to update it, so I can't help you in that regard. Sorry.